# Automatic counter of popularity in mongoose db

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am new at mongoose db.

I have the following schema:

```
var skillSchma = new mongoose.Schema({
    name : {type:String,required: true, unique: true},
    popularity: {type:Number,default:0}
    });

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: { type: Number, required: true, unique: true },
    firstName: { type: String, required: true },
    lastName: { type: String, required: true },
    ...
    skills: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: skillsModule.modelName }],
    ...
});
```

The field popularity at the skills schema is supposed to count the number of users that have that skill (For example, if 3 users have the skill "C++", the C++ popularity will be 3).

How do I make sure that when you add a user, remove a user or change its skills, popularity will be updated automatically ?

I tried to use mongoose db middleware (pre and post). But it does not support the all the changed ways.

Thanks, Itamar

Comment: I don't know much about "Mongoose db middleware (pre and post)", but your data model is redundant and necessarily will imply inconsistency. Why don't you get popularity, when you need it, by a simple count query over the users collection?

Comment: @dgiugg: more expensive and also you now can't sort skills by popularity. This is called "counter cache" and it's a common idiom.

Comment: Ok, let's agree with the fact that it is a common idiom, I just pointed out a real issue that it raises as a secondary effect. Concerning performance, yes indeed it is more expensive relatively but it depends on how much time it takes in absolute terms: if you don't have performance issues, no need to over-optimize (but the OP did not precise this point). For the sorting feature, yes you can: with aggregation. Actually I think we agree on all this points, it is just that there are different ways of doing it, with pros and cons, and I wondered whether the OP considered this other way ;)